# Method Name conventions

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions

Is:

```
- (void) myMethodName;
```

bad form, OK, or just plain wrong, compared to:

```
- (void)myMethodName;
```

I see it done both ways. Same for

```
- (IBAction) myActionName:(id)sender;
```

vs.

```
- (IBAction)myActionName:(id)sender;
```

Comment: Whatever floats your boat, flies your kite, …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about **one space** in between the closing parentheses of the return type and the method name.

This kind of thing is all a matter of personal preference.